# CSS help bubble centering arrow and bubble to align with text

Tags: html, css, bubble-popup

I have a popup bubble that will popup when you hover over the text, I am trying to use it dynamically, however I can not get it to always be centered on the text no matter how tall the bubble is. I've tried everything I can think of, and it won't work :\

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jq2wz/1/

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the jsFiddle you provided?

Comment: I want the bubble and the arrow to be centered vertically with the text. Meaning, the arrow should be in the middle of the bubble vertically, which then the arrow should also be lined up with the help text.

Comment: i think that you should use js for calculate absolute position here.

Comment: I need to use CSS, I know I've done this before, but I can't remember how I did, or at least it's not working now,

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [these](http://forrst.com/posts/Pure_css_tooltip_box_with_arrow_T_R_B_L-7kR), seen in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LqX9Z/) are what you're looking for? Or at least they might be possible to modify to your needs.